# Create a group in sql

Tags: sql, analytic-functions

I have a table with the fields ORDER and FLAG as below and I want to create the GRP column using analytic functions. Can someone adivse how I can do this in sql please?

| ORDER | FLAG | GRP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | 1 |
| 2 | N | 1 |
| 3 | N | 1 |
| 4 | Y | 2 |
| 5 | N | 2 |
| 6 | Y | 3 |
| 7 | Y | 4 |

Comment: On what basis the GRP column is calculated? It does not look like it's a function of Order and FLAG.
The only way you can write a query to compute GRP is if its value can be derived from the value of Order and FLAG.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to start new group at each `'Y'`. Then do running count/sum of them:

```
select
  t.*
  , sum(case flag when 'Y' then 1 end) over(order by order_id asc) as grp
from your_table t
```

Note: never use columns like `order`, `key`, `from` etc as they are reserved keywords in SQL. That's why I renamed `order` to `order_id`.